# Snowflake: How to remove backslash from select query?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There are backslashes in our Snowflake database and I want to replace them with blanks but the replace function is not working.  Is there a way to remove backslashes from a string in Snowflake?

Comment: Please show us your current query.

Answer (score 1):

Are you escaping the backslashes? The escape character for Snowflake string literals is a backslash, so if you want to replace a single backslash you have to put in two backslashes:

```
set my_string = 'My string with one \\ backslash'; --Shows how to escape a backslash 
select $my_string; --Shows the effect of escaping a backslash, only one shows
select replace($my_string, '\\'); --Remove backslashes, replace with nothing
```